# Is it possible to use DECLARE within DO $$...$$;?

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I am a new person for PL/pgSQL. Earlier I have been working on MS T-SQL.
So I am not sure – is it possible to use DECLARE within DO $$...$$;?
I have written the simple code:

```
DO $$
declare x int = 123;
select x;
$$;
```

I have run it in DBeaver console. It returned the following error:

“SQL Error [42704]: ERROR: type "x" does not exist
Position: 37”

The “Position: 37” is the “x” in the “select x”. What is wrong here?

Comment: PL/pgSQL needs a BEGIN for the actual code

Comment: The docs are your friend [plpgsql structure](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-structure.html).

Answer (score 0):

Surely it is. But with different syntax. Attention stored procedures in PostgreSQL and MS SQL are pretty different creatures, and it is better to forgot all about T-SQL and start from zero. It is much more similar to Oracle, although there are differences too. Your example should not to work from two reasons:

1. different syntax
2. anonymous block in Postgres (statement `DO` cannot to return data)

If you can use `psql` then you can use `psql`'s client side session variables like:

```
\set x 123
select :x;
```

or you can use server side custom configure variables:

```
(2023-01-21 06:24:34) postgres=# select set_config('mandatory_prefix.var', '123', false);
┌────────────┐
│ set_config │
╞════════════╡
│ 123        │
└────────────┘
(1 row)

(2023-01-21 06:25:37) postgres=# select current_setting('mandatory_prefix.var');
┌─────────────────┐
│ current_setting │
╞═════════════════╡
│ 123             │
└─────────────────┘
(1 row)
```

Good start is reading [related doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql.html). It is short.